# Performance Counters - Tool for monitoring in Windows Server 2008

Tags: performance, powershell, windows-server-2008

I am able to get Performance counters for every two seconds in `Windows Server 2008` machine using `Powershell` script. But when i go to `Task Manager` and check for the `CPU` Usage, `powershell.exe` is taking 50% of `CPU`. So i am trying to get those Performance counters using other third party tools. I have searched and found [this](http://www.manageengine.com/free-windows-health-monitor/free-windows-health-monitor-index.html) and [this](http://www.petri.co.il/analyze-windows-performance-logs.htm). Those two are need to refresh manually and not getting automatically for every two seconds. Can anyone Please suggest some tool which gives the Performance Counters for every two seconds and analyzes the Maximum, Average of those counters and stores the results in text/xls or any other format. Please help me.

Comment: I'm really surprised that your Powershell script takes 50% CPU while reading perf counters. Could you please share it? Though if you are unhappy with Poershell you may always use windows built-in `typeperf`,eg.:

    `typeperf -cf .\counters.txt -si 1 -o testdata.blg -f BIN -sc 20`

or perfmon, or logman to create a data collector.

Comment: @lowleveldesign i have used `perfmon` but what is this `typeperf`. When i typed `typeperf` in Run window, some command came and disappeared, same for `logman`.. How to use `typeperf`...

Comment: @lowleveldesign i am calling the powershell script for every two seconds using `sleep 2`... Thats why i think it is taking 50% of CPU...

Comment: open command prompt and type `typeperf -?`, `logman` is a bit harder so google for example. For instance, if you would like to collect total CPU usage you may issue: `typeperf "\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Time" -si 1 -sc 20` - this will query perf data every 1s and will stop after 20 samples collected

Comment: @lowleveldesign resulted in `'typeperf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: hmm that's bizarre. Try `C:\Windows\System32\typeperf.exe`

Comment: @lowleveldesign please refer again 2nd comment...

Comment: Well Avadhani Y, I give up - this tool should be in your Windows installation. I can only provide you with a [link to the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753182(v=ws.10).aspx) that also proves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some Performance tools from [here](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/performance-testing-tools-load-testing-tools/), listed below:

1. Apache JMeter
2. NeoLoad
3. LoadRunner
4. LoadUI
5. WebLOAD
6. WAPT
7. Loadster
8. LoadImpact
9. Rational Performance Tester
10. Testing Anywhere
11. OpenSTA
12. QEngine (ManageEngine)
13. Loadstorm
14. CloudTest
15. Httperf.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools that do this -- Google for "server monitor".  Off the top of my head:

1. PA Server Monitor
2. Tembria FrameFlow
3. ManageEngine
4. SolarWinds Orion
5. GFI Max Nagios

Answer (score 0):

SiteScope.   This tool leverages either the perfmon API or the SNMP interface to collect the stats without having to run an additional non-native app on the box.    If you go the open source route then you might consider Hyperic.  Hyperic does require an agent to be on the box.

In either case I would look to your sample window as part of the culprit for the high CPU and not powershell.   The higher your sample rate the higher you will drive the CPU, independent of tool.   You can see this yourself just by running perfmon.   Use the same sets of stats and what what happens to the CPU as you adjust the sample rate from once every 30 seconds, to once in 20, then ten, 5 and finally 2 seconds as the interval.    When engaged in performance testing we rarely go below ten seconds on a host as this will cause the sampling tool to distort the performance of the host.    If we have a particularly long term test, say 24 hours, then adjusting the interval to once in 30 seconds will be enough to spot long term trends in resource utilization.

If you are looking to collect information over a long period of time, 12 hours to more, consider going to a longer term interval.  If you are going for a short period of sampling, an hour for instance, you may want to run a couple of different periods of one hour at lesser and greater levels of sampling (2 seconds vs 10 seconds) to ensure that the shorter sample interval is generating additional value for the additional overhead to the system.

To repeat, tools just to collect OS stats:

- Commercial: SiteScope (Agentless).  Leverages native interfaces
- Open Source: Hyperic (Agent)
- Native:  Perfmon.   Can dump data to a file for further analysis

Comment: Apache JMeter - This tool is excellent!  I have used it for years for performance and load testing with and without VM's and getting data for how many concurrent users a given web page can be requested before you start seeing a drop in response time.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible without third party tools. You should be able to collect the data using Windows Performance Monitor (see [Creating Data Collector Sets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749337(v=ws.11).aspx)) and then translate that data to a custom format using [Tracerpt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490959.aspx).

If you are still looking for other tools, I have compiled a [list of windows server performance monitoring tools](https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools) that also includes third party solutions.